# Dependency Inversion in DDD architecture

Tags: domain-driven-design, solid-principles, dependency-inversion

I divided my project into 4 layers

- Show UI layer
- Service layer processing logic
- The domain layer connects to the data source
- Data layer

If the service layer uses classes in the data layer, does it violate the Dependency Inversion principle in SOLID?

Comment: Possibly not. When you say classes in the data layer do you mean data or behaviour? If your service layer depends on abstractions (e.g. interfaces) for behaviour then no it's not violating DIP.

Comment: Here, I only use the model classes from the datalayer.

Comment: in which case you don't violate DIP

Comment: @qujck, you assume "model classes" are abstractions? I would assume the opposite.

Comment: @jaco0646 not at all - I assume model classes have no behaviour and are therefore not injectables

Comment: if model classes have behaviour that you may want to influence at runtime then you're violating multiple SOLID principles

Comment: @qujck, you should add an answer to this question. The connection between your first comment regarding _abstractions_ and your subsequent comments regarding _models_ is unclear. Do these two things relate to the DIP in the same way?

Answer (score 1):

The Dependency Inversion Principle says:

> High-level modules should not depend on low-level modules. Both should depend on abstractions.

and further

> Abstractions should not depend upon details. Details should depend upon abstractions.

This means: the modules/components/DLLs/packages which contain the application logic should not depend on those which contain "technical details". But this would exactly be the case if your service layer depends on your data layer directly (compile dependencies).

To resolve this you need to define abstractions (interfaces or abstract classes) in the high-level module (your service layer) and let the low-level modules implement those. This way the (compile) dependency is "inverted".

For a more detailed explanation of DIP see also: https://youtu.be/-3Z9L6sIAMM

Comment: How would this work in practice? How does the data layer have any knowledge of interfaces defined in the service layer? And how can it **safely** implement them without a reference?

Comment: In the simplest implementation of DIP the low-level module (data layer) in fact does reference the high-level module (service layer). If you want to avoid this you could apply the adapter pattern (check out the linked video for more detailed explanation)

Comment: With the limited info I have I couldn't disagree more. If the data layer references the service layer then the service layer can't reference the data layer (unless you're proposing circular references). Where are the data models so that both the data layer and the service layer can see them? And where is the Composition Root?

Comment: I agree with u that without concrete context such a discussion is quite difficult. but there are 2 separate questions: 1. should we apply DIP in a particular case? and 2. how to apply DIP correctly. and this SO question is more about the second part. so once one concluded that DIP should be applied the answer above describes how. for the first question we would need a more concrete example and probably a different forum to continue the discussion ;-)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think your layering should be reconsidered. Especially their names don't reveal their intentions. You can use this convention to name your layers:

- The **data layer** is responsible for managing connections and transactions.
- The **domain layer** defines the domain models which act as the persisting data models too.

But to be on the same page I use your terminology. If by Data Layer you mean data models, your answer is yes, it won't break DIP.

Does your service layer define repository (or any other) interfaces that your data layer implements? If your answer is yes, it's a wrong answer. The data layer should define the repository interfaces. It defines what should be retrieved and persisted.

Who would implement the repository interfaces? It's going to be your domain layer. It knows how to access the data and how to translate queries and commands.

So the domain layer and the service layer would not depend on each other, they both depend on the abstractions that the data layer defines. The references between layers would be like the below and as a result, no circular dependencies would be created:

```
service layer => data layer
domain layer => data layer
presentation (UI) layer -> service layer/data layer/domain layer
```

Comment: In my case, the model is only for holding data. So I think that will not break the principle

Comment: this answer aligns closely with my opinion too - the only thing I would change is that repository interfaces *can* be implemented in the data layer but *must* be configured by the application and *should* offer **joinpoints** to support the addition of (cross-cutting) **concerns**

Comment: @qujck Yes it can be but if you want to change the infrastructure, it's not so clean.

Comment: @R.Abbasi theoretically you may be correct but in practice it so rarely happens it's not worth the overhead, additional coupling or complexity.

Comment: @qujck In our experience in domain-driven design, we place the interfaces in the Domain layer and implement them in the Infrastructure layer. It's in the Domain knowledge that what interfaces do. But they don't know how. And in fact, it's so much easier and cleaner. But for this question, I agree with you. Maybe it's not worth the overhead.

Comment: @R.Abbasi agreed, an infrastructure layer is a good solution

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Dependency Inversion requires that your high level modules (like your service layer) is not dependent on low level modules (like your data layer). I think in your case, you should use abstraction (interfaces or abstract classes) that the service layer depends on and the data layer implements.